# Is key-value pair available in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is key-value pair available in TypeScript? If so, how do I do that? Can anyone provide sample, example, or links?

Comment: yes it is,can u specify your requirement ?

Comment: typescript transpiles(not compile) into javascript, so all feature of javascript is available in typescript. e.g. if you write your code in js and change its extension to .ts, it will work as fine as your js code. learn more about it on :- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/.

Answer (score 520):

> Is key-value pair available in Typescript?

Yes. Called [an index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures):

```
interface Foo {
   [key: string]: number;
}


let foo:Foo = {};
foo['hello'] = 123;
foo = {
  'leet': 1337
};
console.log(foo['leet']); // 1337
```

Here keys are `string` and values are `number`.

## More

You can use an es6 `Map` for proper dictionaries, [polyfilled by `core-js`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html#polyfill-for-old-javascript-engines).

Comment: This is a map or dictionary. If you want something equivalent to a C# KeyValuePair, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467469/is-key-value-pair-available-in-typescript/50621451#50621451

Comment: Also nice to know, you don't need to call it `key`. You can, for instance, also write this: `[countryCode: string]: string`. Nice for readability.

Comment: This is the updated link: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures

Comment: Yes, this is a map. But every time I search for "TypeScript Map," all I get is es6 Map, which is *not* what I want! So I'm very thankful that this answer is here.

Comment: you saved me <3

Comment: i keep forgetting the syntax

Comment: I got it with `type Foo = { [key in CustomType]: number; } ;` but that means it needs every key but for a generic mapping,  `type Foo = { CustomType: number; } ;`

Comment: `type Foo = { CustomType: number; } ;` treats `CustomType` as a string "CustomType"

Answer (score 250):

The simplest way would be something like:

```
var indexedArray: {[key: string]: number}
```

Usage:

```
var indexedArray: {[key: string]: number} = {
    foo: 2118,
    bar: 2118
}

indexedArray['foo'] = 2118;
indexedArray.foo= 2118;

let foo = indexedArray['myKey'];
let bar = indexedArray.myKey;
```

Comment: This helped a lot - Less code than the interface approach because it doesn't require describing `Bar`

Comment: Have you got an example usage of this?

Comment: indexedArray = {};
indexedArray["one"] = 1;  /* good **/
indexedArray["two"] = "two";  /* fails */

Comment: Best answer.  Least confusing with simple data types

Answer (score 67):

You can also consider using `Record`, like this:

```
const someArray: Record<string, string>[] = [
    {'first': 'one'},
    {'second': 'two'}
];
```

Or write something like this:

```
const someArray: {key: string, value: string}[] = [
    {key: 'first', value: 'one'},
    {key: 'second', value: 'two'}
];
```

Answer (score 39):

> Is key-value pair available in Typescript?

If you think of a C# [KeyValuePair<string, string>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx): No, but you can easily define one yourself:

```
interface KeyValuePair {
    key: string;
    value: string;
}
```

Usage:

```
let foo: KeyValuePair = { key: "k", value: "val" };
```

Comment: Somewhat funny, already 6 votes with a sum of 0. Would the downvoters mind adding a comment what is bad about this solution?

Comment: I too would like to know. Down voters never leave a comment, I sometimes think because they themselves don't know any better solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this solution doesn't have add, get, remove, etc.

Comment: @DaNeSh That is right. A `KeyValuePair` is not a list, but it could be an entry of a list. Maybe you are looking for a `List<>`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096260/is-there-a-typescript-list-and-or-map-class-library

Comment: How to use the key to get the value? is it like: keyValuePair["k"]?

Comment: **A ``KeyValuePair`` is not a list**. There is just a single key and a single value within. Key: `foo.key` and value: `foo.value`. It seems your are looking for a `List<>` --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096260/is-there-a-typescript-list-and-or-map-class-library

Answer (score 19):

Another simple way is to use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
// Declare a tuple type
let x: [string, number];
// Initialize it
x = ["hello", 10];
// Access elements
console.log("First: " + x["0"] + " Second: " + x["1"]);
```

Output:

> First: hello Second: 10

Answer (score 18):

Not for the questioner, but for all others, which are interested:
See: [How to define Typescript Map of key value pair. where key is a number and value is an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976536/how-to-define-typescript-map-of-key-value-pair-where-key-is-a-number-and-value)

The solution is therefore:

```
let yourVar: Map<YourKeyType, YourValueType>;
// now you can use it:
yourVar = new Map<YourKeyType, YourValueType>();
yourVar[YourKeyType] = <YourValueType> yourValue;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Where is `Map` defined? Is it Angular-specific?

Comment: @JackMiller Map is defined by ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: yourVar[YourKeyType] = XXX. This does not set an element in the Map. It does set a property.

Comment: IE browser doesn't support Map, any alternative?

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay plain objects.

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay Drop IE? :D

Answer (score 13):

an example of a key value pair is:

`[key: string]: string`

you can put anything as the value, of course

Comment: `export default interface KeyValuePair {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean;
}`


Is slightly better, but is this weak typing? Does this defeat the purpose to some extent?

Comment: Yes but when you have array of those like `newRows: { [key: string]: string; }[]` then filter wont work `this.newRows = this.newRows.filter(x=>x.length>0)` 
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.ts(2365)
x is an item of the array to supposed to be an array itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

A concise way is to use a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) as [key-value pair](https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries):

```
const keyVal: [string, string] =  ["key", "value"] // explicit type
const keyVal2 = ["key", "value"] as const // inferred type with const assertion
const [key, val] = ["key", "val"] // usage with array destructuring
```

You can create a generic `KeyValuePair` type for reusability:

```
type KeyValuePair<K extends PropertyKey, V = unknown> = [K, V]
const kv: KeyValuePair<string, string> = ["key", "value"]
```

#### TS 4.0

[provides](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#labeled-tuple-elements) [labeled tuple elements](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38234) for better documentation and tooling support:

```
type KeyValuePairNamed = [key: string, value: string] // "key" and "value" labels
```

#### Compatibility

`[key, value]` tuples also ensure compatibility to JS built-in objects:

- [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), esp. [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), esp. [`Map.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`new Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) constructor
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), esp. [`Set.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/entries)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4DUCGAbAXDA2tAJwEswBzAGhkJNIF0YBePAIkSWcuYDdMBXBZvQD0QmAgAeABwxFgRWFCSSEAWABQoSLDboMAJkYs2HGNz4D6aCDE3QYImCQBmCAgQQATGIuUwA7vIAFjbgdlYQrlBE4Oq2sLhslDwY9Ey4rMgmZhiC9qK8Ef5BMGhuaEgwHgiEvMBQvMRkMOrqPggwANLIuvwACmhEBAA8HWLiUAhgHta9BCDKBIpdSJQohrxgcGAgfmAAfIa4Hau0saHaXDjLPQj9g0PUZJSPpAdpGeycyfyCLWoOABUAMowAAsADoAAzNNRtTrdcx3AgAOTQAFtPIc2DgXklzDioI06HkYAADNikkpTMnfBCUjBoABGCAwECAA)

Comment: how do I use this KeyValuePairNamed?

Comment: Just write `const kvp: KeyValuePairNamed = ["mykey", "myval"]`. The labels are a type-only construct for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 5):

One can also simple use Record

```
type Foo = Record<string, number>
```

Further usage in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
    private key: T1;
    private value: T2;

    constructor(key: T1, value: T2) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
const myPair = new Pair<string, number>('test', 123);
console.log(myPair.getKey(), myPair.getValue());
```

Comment: This is not helpfull if you're trying to type data coming from the backend.

Comment: @MathijsSegers This class is not meant to be a concrete type.  Use this class as a derived type into your concrete type

Answer (score 1):

KeyValue interface exists in angular library that uses typescript.
So you have this generic interface to use if your project is angular.
Or you can use its declaration to get a nice generic KeyValue interface if you are not using TS in angular.

[image]

```js
export declare interface KeyValue<K, V> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
}
```

Comment: What about those who don't use Angular?

Comment: @fdrobidoux generally for typescript you will see, eg, `Record<string, number>` (simply replace "KeyValue" with "Record".

Comment: good one for angular. Instead of making custom class

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has Map. You can use like:

```
public myMap = new Map<K,V>([
[k1, v1],
[k2, v2]
]);

myMap.get(key); // returns value
myMap.set(key, value); // import a new data
myMap.has(key); // check data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const YAHOO = 'YAHOO';
const GOOGLE = 'GOOGLE';
const google = 'google';
const yahoo = 'yahoo';

type DomainKeyType = typeof GMAIL | typeof GOOGLE;
type DomainValueType = typeof google | typeof yahoo;

type DomainType = Record<DomainKeyType , DomainValueType>

const domain: DomainType = {
  YAHOO: yahoo,
  GOOGLE: google,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use below example

Example: {
value1: "value1"
}

And add conditionalData dynamically based on some condition, Try

```
let dataToWrite: any = {value1: "value1"};

if(conditionalData)
   dataToWrite["conditionalData"] = conditionalData
```