# How to define Typescript Map of key value pair. where key is a number and value is an array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

In my angular2 app i want to create a map which takes a number as key and returns an array of objects. I am currently implementing in following way but no luck. How should i implement it or should i use some other data structure for this purpose? I want to use map because maybe its fast?

**Declaration**

```
 private myarray : [{productId : number , price : number , discount : number}];

priceListMap : Map<number, [{productId : number , price : number , discount : number}]> 
= new Map<number, [{productId : number , price : number , discount : number}]>();
```

**Usage**

```
this.myarray.push({productId : 1 , price : 100 , discount : 10});
this.myarray.push({productId : 2 , price : 200 , discount : 20});
this.myarray.push({productId : 3 , price : 300 , discount : 30});
this.priceListMap.set(1 , this.myarray);
this.myarray = null;

this.myarray.push({productId : 1 , price : 400 , discount : 10});
this.myarray.push({productId : 2 , price : 500 , discount : 20});
this.myarray.push({productId : 3 , price : 600 , discount : 30});
this.priceListMap.set(2 , this.myarray);
this.myarray = null;

this.myarray.push({productId : 1 , price : 700 , discount : 10});
this.myarray.push({productId : 2 , price : 800 , discount : 20});
this.myarray.push({productId : 3 , price : 900 , discount : 30});
this.priceListMap.set(3 , this.myarray);
this.myarray = null;
```

I want to get an array of 3 objects if i use `this.priceList.get(1);`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

First thing, define a type or interface for your object, it will make things much more readable:

```
type Product = { productId: number; price: number; discount: number };
```

You used [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of size one instead of array, it should look like this:

```
let myarray: Product[];
let priceListMap : Map<number, Product[]> = new Map<number, Product[]>();
```

So now this works fine:

```
myarray.push({productId : 1 , price : 100 , discount : 10});
myarray.push({productId : 2 , price : 200 , discount : 20});
myarray.push({productId : 3 , price : 300 , discount : 30});
priceListMap.set(1 , this.myarray);
myarray = null;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Product%20%3D%20%7B%20productId%3A%20number%2C%20price%3A%20number%2C%20discount%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20myarray%3A%20Product%5B%5D%3B%0Alet%20priceListMap%20%3A%20Map%3Cnumber%2C%20Product%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cnumber%2C%20Product%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0A%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%201%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20100%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2010%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%202%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20200%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2020%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%203%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20300%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2030%7D)%3B%0ApriceListMap.set(1%20%2C%20this.myarray)%3B%0Amyarray%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%201%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20400%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2010%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%202%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20500%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2020%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%203%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20600%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2030%7D)%3B%0ApriceListMap.set(2%20%2C%20this.myarray)%3B%0Amyarray%20%3D%20null%3B%0A%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%201%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20700%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2010%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%202%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20800%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2020%7D)%3B%0Amyarray.push(%7BproductId%20%3A%203%20%2C%20price%20%3A%20900%20%2C%20discount%20%3A%2030%7D)%3B%0ApriceListMap.set(3%20%2C%20this.myarray)%3B%0Amyarray%20%3D%20null%3B))

Comment: In your playground link there is an error in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) I implemented it using an interface and i got the same error.

Comment: That's because I just copied your code, and in your code you are setting `myarray` to null and then try to push to it.  So either don't set it to null, or just reassign a new array later

Comment: I am getting error on type keyword, using typescript 2.1.0

Comment: @Faisalkhan That shouldn't happen. Type aliases were added in [typescript 1.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-aliases). What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 12):

The most simple way is to use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type `Record<number, productDetails>`

```
interface productDetails {
   productId : number , 
   price : number , 
   discount : number
};

const myVar : Record<number, productDetails> = {
   1: {
       productId : number , 
       price : number , 
       discount : number
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also skip creating dictionary altogether. i used below approach to same problem .

```js
     mappedItems: {};
     items.forEach(item => {     
            if (!mappedItems[item.key]) {
              mappedItems[item.key] = [];
            }
            mappedItems[item.key].push({productId : item.productId , price : item.price , discount : item.discount}));
        });
```