# map.get is not a function while retrieving a value from a map in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am having a map with key and value as strings. However when trying to retrieve a value based on the key it is throwing error .

the following is my code snippet.

```
let map:Map<string, string> =  {  [ "key1": "hello world 1" ], ["key2": "hello world 2"] } ;
alert( JSON.stringify(map.get("key"))  );
```

the exception i got below is as follows.

```
VM133:4 Uncaught TypeError: map.get is not a function
    at eval (eval at exec (typescript.js:41), <anonymous>:4:26)
    at exec (typescript.js:41)
    at HTMLDocument.runScripts (typescript.js:41)
```

appreciate if you can tell me what am I doing wrong

thank you

Comment: THat's not correct JSON. You want this, I guess, `let map: Record<string, string> = { key1: "hello world 1", key2: "hello world 2" };`

Comment: what is Record ?

Comment: A utility type https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype

Comment: i am still getting the same error

Comment: `alert( JSON.stringify(Object.keys(map)));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Map` is not a primitive and needs to be called with the constructor (I think Typescript should have warned about this).

See the [MDN documentation for `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/)

You're probably looking for this:

```
const map:Map<string, string> = new Map([
  [ "key1", "hello world 1" ], 
  [ "key2", "hello world 2" ],
])
```

Comment: This won't compile. `[ "key1": "hello world 1" ]` is invalid tuple/array.

Comment: @Nishant Thanks, was just fixing that. My bad, copy/pasted too quickly

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create a map like this in typescript, you're missing the constructor call. What you've right now is just an object literal that is also formatted in a wrong way.

```
let myMap = new Map([
        ["key1", "value1"],
        ["key2", "value2"]
    ]);
alert( JSON.stringify(map.get("key1"))  );
```

Comment: can i ask a quick question . How can i declare [
        ["key1", "value1"],
        ["key2", "value2"]
    ] this as a typed variable . is let arr:[ [string,string] ] , is this correct ?

Comment: hmmm, I think you'd have to define your Maps interfaces, like this, `interface myMap { // whatever your key and values }`

Comment: I have found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976536/how-to-define-typescript-map-of-key-value-pair-where-key-is-a-number-and-value, you can check it and see if it serves your purposes