# Importing List type in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning angular2+ and Typescript for the first time and I'm having issues with one the code samples from this [website](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/).

One of his code samples uses type `List` but I don't where the author imported this type from. I have tried installing and importing `typescript-collections` but it doesn't have an implementation of `List`.

How can I install and import the module that contains type `List`?

**Update:**

Here's the snippet of code that uses `List`

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoStore {
    private _todos: BehaviorSubject<List<Todo>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));

    public readonly todos: Observable<List<Todo>> = this._todos.asObservable();

    constructor(private todoBackendService: TodoBackendService) {
        this.loadInitialData();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: it would help a lot if you gave us your code snippet so we can get some context...

Comment: What do you want from that `List` that `Array` doesn't have?

Comment: Here he imported list: import {List} from 'immutable';

Comment: [what about this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23106997/5621827)

Comment: If you're coming from a C# background, then I understand why you would want to use `List` however javascript (typescript) `Array` is a very similar implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in question is using a list imported from the [Immutable JS](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) library. You can install that library with your package manager of choice.

For example, with NPM

```
$ npm install immutable --save
```

with JSPM

```
$ jspm install immutable
```

with Yarn

```
$ yarn add immutable
```

Immutable JS ships with its own type declarations so you do not need to add anything else.

That said, consider sticking with a simple array for now until you find yourself needing anything more complex.

Comment: Awesome. That worked and good to know.

I'll refactor the code to use Array instead.