# How do I enable Typescripts native List?

Tags: typescript, list

I read that Typescript now support List<> as native here

[Is there a typescript List<> and/or Map<> class/library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096260/is-there-a-typescript-list-and-or-map-class-library)

And that you can enable it with `lib.d.ts` but how? I found the file in the node_modules and I don't think I should edit that right? And even if I should edit it, what should I add/remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not add new runtime constructs to the language (with the notable exception of namespaces, which are pretty much deprecated, and enums).

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a JavaScript concept, therefore it is supported by TypeScript. `List`, however, is not.

There's no native implementation of `List` in TypeScript. Use an array.