# Typescript List functionality with equals operator

Tags: typescript, list, return, equals, operator-keyword

I was looking to create my own typescript array with extra functionality.
I came across this post:
[To post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096260/is-there-a-typescript-list-and-or-map-class-library)

There they suggest making a list class as follow

```
class List<T> {
public items: Array<T>;

constructor() {
    this.items = [];
}

size(): number {
    return this.items.length;
}

add(value: T): void {
    this.items.push(value);
}

get(index: number): T {
    return this.items[index];
}}
```

All works fine.
Only problem is when I assign the list to another reference wanting the array from list. I always have to add the items ref.

Example

```
myList:List<string> = new List();
ArrayItems = myList.items;
```

Is there a way in typescript to decide what will be returned when using the equals (=) operator?

Comment: I guess you can fix it by defining a default value for your generic like `string`: `class List<T = string> { ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to override the assignment operator like this. However, you may be able to achieve what you want in other ways. For instance, do you need to access the underlying array from outside the class, or can you get by without it? For example, if you want to add support for `for..of` and spread syntax `[...]`, all you need to do is turn your class into an "iterable"; you can also define your own `map`, `filter`, `reduce` methods (and more), and simply "proxy" the inputs to your underlying array's associated built in method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a deeper look into this and found out the following code works

```
export class List<T> extends Array<T> {

constructor(array:Array<T> = []) {
  super();

  for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   this.add(array[i])
}

  size(): number {
      return this.length;
  }

  add(value: T): void {
      this.push(value);
  }

  public clear(){
      this.splice(0, this.length);
  }
}
```

Now I can create an object of List with new and use the default constructor or add an array in the constructor parenthesis.

When I now want the array I can reference to the list Object.
I guess Typescript automatically selects the Array I'm extending.

```
private myList:List<string>;
private arrayTest[];

public Init()
{
  this.myList= new List(); //Default constructor
  this.myList= new List(["A","B","C"]); //Constructor with params
  this.arrayTest = this.mysList; //Selects automatically the array
}
```

The code in the constructor makes this List object referring to the correct array data. Filling parameters to the super constructor of Array would create a new object and won't work 100% correctly     `super(...array)`

Hope this is useful to someone.