# typescript use object as the type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have

```
clients/
  index.ts
  client1.ts
  client2.ts
myApp.ts

// client1.ts
export default class Client1 {}
// client2.ts
export default class Client2 {}

// clients/index.ts
import Client1 from './client1';
import Client2 from './client2';
export { client1, client2 };
```

Now, I want to use all of clients in myApp and set the type to be based on this, i.e.

```js
// myApp.ts

import * as clients from './clients';

type Clients = {
 [key in keyof typeof clients]: clients[key];
}

const allClients: Clients = {
  client1: new clients.Client1(),
  client2: new clients.Client2(),
}
```

The code above is not valid, `clients[key];` throws an error about `Cannot use namespace 'clients' as a type.` but I basically want to be able to import all of the clients, and use that object as the type definition for all my clients. Is this possible?

Comment: Do the clients have anything extend from a same interface/class? Or are they completely different?

Comment: How many typos are in this question? On the face of it you want `(typeof clients)[key]` instead of `clients[key]`, but how can you export `{client1, client2}` when there's nothing named `client1` or `client2` in scope? And then your `allClients` holds class instances but the type implies constructors instead. You could maybe do [this](//codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-6bqzk?file=/myApp.ts) but I would definitely prefer a [mre] in the question where the only problem is the one you're asking about.  Like [this](//tsplay.dev/N7K1PN), maybe... does that answer your question?

Comment: @kks21199 they are completely different

Comment: If you create an interface containing common methods between the clients, you can store them in a list and access them. This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23106997/3126835  this will still require you to manually add the clients to the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the interface manually?
I don't think you're going to be able to create it on the fly like that. And you probably want your types to be static at runtime anyway. They'll be much easier to reason about.

Just define an interface with the clients listed either myApp or where you export them.

```
import * as clients from './clients';

interface Clients = {
   client1: clients.client1,
   client2: clients.client2,
}

const allClients: Clients = {
  client1: new clients.Client1(),
  client2: new clients.Client2(),
}
```

Comment: That is an option, I want to see if this can be dynamic that requires no manual definition.

Comment: tsc runs at compile time, and I don't think tsc contains a javascript runtime that would let it execute arbitrary javascript code. I don't think this is possible.